# how to find the table row count in hive query using group by

Tags: hadoop, hive

Here my question: I have a table with some records like (name, date, type). Suppose I have three type a, b and c.Now I want to count percentage of each type mean COUNT(type)/COUNT(table row count)??

```
       select type,COUNT(type) as counttype,counttype/(select COUNT(*) from xyz) from xyz group by xyz;
```

"(select COUNT(*) from xyz)" this giving me error.
How to find the table Row Count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can use below query :-

select A.type,A.type_cnt,(A.type_cnt/B.total_cnt) from
(Select type,count(type) as type_cnt from xyz group by type)A
JOIN
(select count(*)as total_cnt from xyz)B
ON 1=1;

Answer (score 0):

Without JOIN it is much faster, using analytic function:

```
select type,
       count(type) as type_cnt, 
       count(type)/count(*) over() as pct  
  from xyz 
 group by type;
```